# How to create true color of Landsat 8 C2 and How to assign 0 to cloud pixels and 1 to non-cloud pixels after cloudmasking in GEE?

Tags: cloud, google-earth-engine, libgee

I want to see the true color image of my raw image to compare the cloudmasked image but the output of my function is pure white.

Moreover, I am planning to determine the pixel percentage of each barangays from a feature collection, based the cloudmasked image collection of Landsat 8 Collection 2. But I don't know how to reclassify the pixels from the cloudmask to 0 and 1 to compute the percentage based on the number of pixels within the zone.

Here's my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/53697fc35f5b6952ca08d0ea6644355e

Thank you in advance.